# Bhajans and stotras for mleccha/unitiated person to chant at midday and sunset?

Tags: mantras, rituals, gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSuSfHslwwY) claims that a person who has not undergone upanayana, can receive similar benefits to sandhya vandanam by chanting Aditya Hrudayam at sunrise followed by japa of the sarva gayatri mantra.

Are there any bhajans or stotras that are appropriate for an uninitiated person to recite at midday and sunset?